# Использование SELF JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.Зачем нужна конструкциz JOIN когда идет выборка с одной таблици?
С той информации что я прочитал так я понял что она используется для удаления дубликатов.
можно примерами подкрепить использование данного приема?
Благодарен

Answer (score 3):

> Зачем нужна конструкциz JOIN когда идет выборка с одной таблици?

Скажем, если вам в одной строке нужно соединить разные строки одной таблицы.

Answer (score 2):

Довольно старый пример, но:
Отношение такого вида

Employees
(
 Employee_ID,
  Manager_ID
)

То есть сотрудник и его менеджер, нам нужно выбрать менеджеров на один уровень вверх, то есть получим результат вида

(Работник) | (Менеджер на один уровень выше)

SELECT e1.employee_id, e2.manager_ID
FROM Employees e1 JOIN Employees e2 ON e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id